# samsung galaxy s 2 debugging without battery

Tags: android, debugging, usb, battery

I am currently doing quite a lot of android development and I am usung my galaxy s 2 to debug via usb. I was wondering if there was a way to debug without having to keep the battery in the phone as I dont want to wear it out (the battery life is short enough as it is! lol)

I'm guessing this would require some device that completes the circuit in the same way as the battery does and swapping it for the battery whenever I want to debug. that or just get a second battery?

Just thought that I'd ask on here hoping that one of the other android developers have also had this problem and found a solution :)

Comment: I'm sure there is a power supply interface / fake battery for hardware development. You'll have to track it down.  It'll have limited use outside of for hardware development/testing, so it'll require some hunting and will probably be quite expensive. Personally, I'd get a 2nd battery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your phone is rooted you can debug over wifi.  No idea why this isn't available for non-rooted phones.

[How can I connect to Android with ADB over TCP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2604727/how-can-i-connect-to-android-with-adb-over-tcp)

If you don't want to debug but just run then you could use EStrong File Explorer to install and run the app over your LAN via wifi.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion but unfortunately this doesn't help me :( I am wirking as an intern at the moment and I am debugging on my own phone and laptop, weither of which I am allowed to connect to the network :( So I cant get internet on  my laptop (have a comp at my desk for internet)

Answer (score 1):

If your phone won't turn on without the battery, you've not much choice.

You might be pleasantly surprised how cheap the batteries are though - I've got an older android whose battery I killed in a similar way, and I got a replacement for only £7 (about $12).  I keep the old battery around now for things like this.